# slow server download

Tags: server, downloads

I'm trying to download the latest LTS server.  The first time I tried it estimated about 30 minutes which I felt was too long, so I canceled the d/l and restarted.  It went up to about 45 minutes.  Cancelled again, waited about 5 minutes and restarted another d/l.  Now it wants an hour to do it.  What gives?  Is ubuntu just that popular or did I trigger some kind of anti-d/l mechanism or am I just lucky, or is there a real problem here?

Comment: Where are you downloading from (the website, torrent?), and what is your connection speed.

Answer (score 0):

I would try one of the mirror sites. There's a list of mirror sites on the Alternative Downloads page, so pick one close to you and enjoy a speedy download!

[Alternative Downloads page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads)